# Repeatedly applying a rotation matrix in 4-d space leads to cool shapes. What are they?

Tags: vector-spaces, rotations

I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715286/repeated-applications-of-a-rotation-matrix-keep-you-in-the-same-subspace/4715324#4715324) about applying a rotation matrix repeatedly to a unit vector and the shape this traces out. In 3-d space, this shape is a circle (for any rotation matrix).

I wanted to see what happens when I apply the same process to 4-d space. Start with some random point on the unit 4-sphere. Then, get a bunch of points by repeatedly applying the rotation matrix. What kind of curve do these points trace out? I was expecting either a circle or a sphere. Instead when I coded it up [here](https://gist.github.com/ryu577/cd47133626fd418b1dc594d043a34bdb), I got fascinating shapes. For instance, with the rotation matrix:

```
array([[ 0.99453664, -0.06742293, -0.05980238, -0.05267533],
   [ 0.06015838,  0.99409722, -0.06764144, -0.05980238],
   [ 0.06026834,  0.05993827,  0.99409722, -0.06742293],
   [ 0.0603785 ,  0.06026834,  0.06015838,  0.99453664]])
```

Applying this process leads to the shape below.

[image]

And for this rotation matrix:

```
array([[ 0.73135688, -0.65783315, -0.17987134,  0.00435448],
   [ 0.35220291,  0.58417312, -0.70876031, -0.17987134],
   [ 0.39091574,  0.27052209,  0.58417312, -0.65783315],
   [ 0.43388374,  0.39091574,  0.35220291,  0.73135688]])
```

[image]

What looks like a bunch of circles.

A bunch of other rotation matrices yield bangle like shapes like the first one.

I need help understanding what these shapes are.

Edit: it's clear the shapes are toroid. How do I determine the small amd large radii of the toroid? And how does this make sense when every point should be equidistant from the center of the original sphere?

Comment: Looks like torus to me. The 2nd picture looks like a bunch of circles probably because the two rotational angles embedded in the matrix is close to commensurable. ie. the ratio is closed to a rational number with small numerator and denominator. If I didn't make any mistake, the ratio is $3.957 \sim 4$.

Comment: Interesting. What would the small and big radii of this torus be? Where did the two radii even come from?

Comment: To get that, you probably need to explicit diagonalize the matrix, get the two 2-dim space for each rotation and compute the projection of your initial vector to them.

Comment: In 3d space it isn't possible for every point of a toroid to be equidistant from the origin. In 4d space it somehow becomes possible?

Comment: Yes. a simple example is the points $(\frac35\cos\theta,\frac35\sin\theta,\frac45\cos\phi,\frac45\sin\phi)$ lie on a torus $\subset S^3$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to visualize that this will be a Torus?

Comment: A rotation matrix in 3D has to have an axis that is fixed. points on this axis are not moved by the rotation. Points off the axis don't change their distance from the axis, nor do they change their distance from $0$, which forces them in a circle. But in 4D, there no longer needs to be a single fixed axis. You can rotate about two independent axes at the same time. This moving around in two circles forms a torus. In 4D, the torus is a subset of the 4-sphere and both circles are the same size. Your picture has differing radii because of how you chose to project 4D space into 3D.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - thanks a lot. This helps me very much. If you get some time, I'd really appreciate it if you could answer this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716277/parametrize-4-d-torus-to-standard-torus-equations