# Parametrize 4-d Torus to standard Torus equations

Tags: geometry, parametric, spherical-coordinates

Based on a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715883/repeatedly-applying-a-rotation-matrix-in-4-d-space-leads-to-cool-shapes-what-ar), the following 4-d parametrization represents a Torus (it also happens to lie completely on $S^3$):

$$
x=3/5 \cos(\theta)\\
y=3/5 \sin(\theta)\\
z=4/5 \cos(\phi)\\
w=4/5 \sin(\phi)
$$

I'm trying to represent these as the standard equations of a Torus:

$$
x=(R+r \cos(\alpha))\cos(\beta)\\
y=(R+r \cos(\alpha))\sin(\beta)\\
z = r \sin(\alpha)
$$

That will tell me what the $R$ and $r$ parameters of the 4-d Torus are.

---

My attempt:

From the first set of equations, $w$ is already in the correct form (if we assume $\alpha = \phi$). We can express $z$ as a function of $w$. Now I don't know how to infiltrate the $x$ and $y$ which don't depend on $z$ and $w$ in any way.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. The first object lives in $\Bbb R^4$ and the second lives in $\Bbb R^3$. They are diffeomorphic (smoothly "the same") but not isometric. Changing $r$ and $R$ changes the curvature of the torus in $\Bbb R^3$, but all the tori given by such equations in $\Bbb R^4$ are flat ($0$ curvature). Both surfaces are abstractly $S^1\times S^1$. That's the best you can do.

Comment: For the first, 4-d Torus, I'd like to find the $R$ and $r$ parameters. Does this not make sense?

Comment: If you see the image here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715883/repeatedly-applying-a-rotation-matrix-in-4-d-space-leads-to-cool-shapes-what-ar, I can "see" the $R$ and $r$.

Comment: No, it does not make sense for reasons I already explained.

Comment: @TedShifrin - there is a lot of reading for me to do, can you recommend any introductory book? Also, how can the $\Bbb{R}^4$ toroid be flat when it lies on the surface of a sphere? Isn't anything on the surface of the sphere curved since the space itself is curved?

Comment: It has intrinsic curvature $0$, just as a cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$ has (even though it has some extrinsic curvature). Both surfaces can be unrolled into a flat piece of paper. … I don’t know your level or background, but you are welcome to download my differential geometry text on curves and surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ (linked in my profile). But there is no discussion in there of the flat torus in $\Bbb R^4$.